# How can I get the value of a HTML text?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is part of my HTML code:

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
    <label>Amount</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" name="amounter" id="amounter" required />
    </div>
}
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".btn.btn-info.btn-lg-add").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url;

        if ($("#amounter").val() == undefined || $("#amounter").val() == null) {
            url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("NoAmount", "Cart"))';
        }

        else {
            var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {idinput = "IDI",amount="AM"}))';
            url = url.replace("AM", $("#amounter").val());
            url = url.replace("IDI", $(this).data("id"));
        }

          window.location.href = url;
    });

</script>
```

Note that each text is followed by an unique button.
Obviously I'm having problems with `id="amounter"` due to duplications. So this is not correct code.

So with the fact that I have multiple texts (because of the `foreach`), how can I refer spesific text?

Comment: Use `for` loop instead of `foreach` to generate unique IDs for each textboxes & use jQuery ID selector to refer certain textbox element. Also `name` attribute value should be generated in same manner as `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, each text is followed by an unique button. then if input text element is to the left of  you can find it like this:

```
$(".btn.btn-info.btn-lg-add").on('click', function(){
   text =  $(this).prev('input').val();
});
```

If input is after  then you can find it like this:

```
$('.btn.btn-info.btn-lg-add').on('click', function(){
   text =  $(this).next('input').val();
});
```

Comment: Add some class to your text input element and here you go!! $(this).prev('input.someClass:text').val();

Answer (score 0):

You can add a number so the id is unique

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
                        <label>Amount</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" name="amounter" id="amounter_@(i)" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use this idea but not the exact one. I’m not by my computer now so i’ll you know later whether it worked

Answer (score 0):

you can using `$('input[name="amounter"]')` for reference it

which you can check the value by console.log();

and when you're want to get data you can used

```
$.map($('input[name="amounter"]'),function(c){return c.value;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guy  may be can help you

```js
$.each($("[name=amounter]"), function (index, data) {
                                     
 console.log($("[name=amounter]:eq("+index+")").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Amount1</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input type="text" name="amounter" id="amounter_@1" required value="data1" />
</div>

<label>Amount2</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input type="text" name="amounter" id="amounter_@2" required value="data2" />
</div>


<label>Amount3</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input type="text" name="amounter" id="amounter_@3" required  value="data3"/>
</div>
```